# Core Plot: x-axis labels not plotted when using scaleToFitPlots

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, core-plot

**Problem:** I can't get Core Plot (1.1) to plot automatic labels for my **x**-axis when using autoscaling (`[plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[graph allPlots]`).

**What I have tried:** I changed the values for the offsets and paddings, but this did not change the result.
However, when turning autoscale off (not using `[plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[graph allPlots]]`and setting the **y** scale automatically, the automatic labeling of the **x**-axis works.

**Question**: Is there a bug in Core Plot or what did I do wrong?
I would appreciate any help!

Thank you!

This is how I have set up my chart:

```
CPTBarPlot *barPlot = [CPTBarPlot 
   tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor blueColor] horizontalBars:NO];
barPlot.baseValue       = CPTDecimalFromInt(0);
barPlot.barOffset       = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f); // CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.5f);
barPlot.barWidth        = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.4f);
barPlot.barCornerRadius = 4;
barPlot.labelOffset = 5;
barPlot.dataSource      = self;
barPlot.delegate        = self;
 
graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
   self.hostView.hostedGraph = graph;
    
graph.paddingLeft   = 40.0f;
graph.paddingTop    = 30.0f;
graph.paddingRight  = 30.0f;
graph.paddingBottom = 50.0f;
        
[graph addPlot:barPlot];
        
graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;
graph.plotAreaFrame.cornerRadius  = 0.0f;
graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = borderLineStyle;
    
double xAxisStart = 0;
CPTXYAxisSet *xyAxisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
CPTXYAxis *xAxis = xyAxisSet.xAxis;
CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [xAxis.axisLineStyle mutableCopy];
lineStyle.lineCap = kCGLineCapButt;
xAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
xAxis.majorTickLength = 10;
xAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal   = CPTDecimalFromDouble(yAxisStart);
xAxis.paddingBottom = 5;
        
xyAxisSet.delegate = self;
xAxis.delegate = self;
xAxis.labelOffset = 0;
         
xAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;

[plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[graph allPlots]];
        
CPTMutablePlotRange *yRange = plotSpace.yRange.mutableCopy;
[yRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromDouble(1.3)];
plotSpace.yRange = yRange;
NSInteger xLength = CPTDecimalIntegerValue(plotSpace.xRange.length) + 1;
        
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange
plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(xAxisStart) 
   length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(xLength)] ;
```

### Edit

Eric's answer has helped. The x-labels are now plotted, but at the wrong y-position (offset). How can I have them plotted right below the x-axis (please refer to the screenshots below):[image][image]).

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `orthogonalCoordinateDecimal` for the axes after scaling the plot space. Just a guess, but the the `yAxisStart` value used to position the x-axis might be outside the scaled range.

Comment: Eric, your answer helped me: The labels for the x-axis are now plotted. However, they are plotted at incorrect y-values (I have added two screenshots to my question). How can I have them plotted right below the x-axis? Thank you.

Comment: The easiest way would be to create a second x-axis. Set the axis line and tick styles to `nil` to make it invisible, position it at the bottom of the plot area using constraints, and attach the labels to the second x-axis instead of the first. All three axes can share the same plot space. Turn off the labels on the first x-axis.

Comment: I have added a second x-axis (named it `xLabelAxis`) and configured it the way you recommended. But how can I set its constraints to position at the bottom of the plot (I am still struggling to understand the concept of constraints in Core Plot).

Comment: `xAxis2.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];`

Comment: AlexR - what was the working code after resolving this? I am having the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and patched it by adding another plot with lineWidth:0.0 and clearColor at (x,y) values of (-1,-1). scaleToFit includes this plot and shows my labels and axis.